# microsoft.visualstudio.diagnostics.servicemodelsink.dll -- present on most systems, missing on new system

Tags: .net

- ASP.NET app,
- Win2012-R2
- .NET 4.6.1 installed

We are setting up our app on a new IIS / Win2012-R2 server, and our app throws this error:

```
The type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.Behavior, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' registered for extension 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.Behavior' could not be loaded. (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config line 241)
```

We see that this dll:

`microsoft.visualstudio.diagnostics.servicemodelsink.dll` is missing. It is present on our other servers.

Where does it come from? (it is in the GAC magically on our existing Win2012R2 servers)

We have carefully reviewed the pieces of Windows installed, and are confident all the Windows pieces present on the old servers are also on the new server.

Comment: I've just had this same problem, but I also want that assembly installed rather than editing the machine.config. I've checked that .NET 4 is already installed on this machine, but for some reason ServiceModelSink and some other assemblies are missing from the GAC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved. Hacking at machine.config (which I do not love to do when I do not fully understand the implications of what I am doing)... I basically followed the error message, and commented out:

```
commonBehaviors/endpointBehaviors
```

That resulted in the error changing to a different line of machine.config, so commented out:

```
serviceBehaviors
```

And no more errors, and app runs great.

Would be nice to know what this all means.